# SQL: Joining Same Column Twice For Criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have a column called member.id which is present in a table called poster as both poster.sender and poster.reciever.

I need a query which selects member.value where the member.id is either the poster.sender OR poster.reciever.

[i know the names dont make much sense - i didnt come up with them]

So far i have this and it isnt working:

```
SELECT member.value
FROM ((poster INNER JOIN member ON poster.sender = member.ID) 
INNER JOIN poster ON poster.sender= member.id

WHERE (member.id <> ?
AND (((poster.Sender = ?) OR (poster.reciever = ?))AND (poster.Status = 'Accepted'))
```

Any ideas would be super helpful!

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What does "Accepted" have to do with your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    member.value
FROM 
    poster s INNER JOIN member ON s.sender = member.ID
INNER JOIN poster r ON r.receiver = member.id
WHERE 
    member.id <> ?
AND 
    (
        s.sender = ? 
    OR r.reciever = ?
    ) 
AND 
    s.status = 'Accepted'
```

you cannot use a table twice in a query without alias, hence the alias `s` and `r`.

Also change where condition according to your requirement -> `status = 'Accepted'` from sender or receiver table or both.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this...

```
select distinct(value)
from
(
(select member.value from member inner join poster on member.id = poster.sender) 
union 
(select member.value from member inner join poster on member.id = poster.receiver) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT value
       FROM member
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM poster
                            WHERE member.id IN (poster.sender,
                                                poster.receiver));
```

Should be equivalent to N Mason's but probably faster. At least it doesn't need to eliminate duplicates for the `UNION` (hoping the optimizer ignores the outer `DISTINCT` as the results from the `UNION` are already distinct and does not uselessly do it again). Elimination of duplicates can be pricy.